# OctoberCMS - The operation timed out. Please increase the server's timeout and try again

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, octobercms, lampp

I have Ubuntu 16.04 , lampp server, PHP version 7.x i am trying to install latest version of OctoberCMS.

I have done everything from setting up database to setting up proper file permissions in my local server.

But I am keep getting the error saying

```
The operation timed out. Please increase the server's timeout and try again.
```

Below is the screenshot what I am getting when I am trying to install OctoberCMS.

[image]

Here is the **Apache** link they are referring in error page - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

I went through with this and did some research and went through with this thread https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/3176

Here I found saying to increase **fastcgi_read_timeout**  but I guess its only for **nginx** server as I m yet to find in **apache** to increase the  **fastcgi_read_timeout** in apache server.

Do I need to install **nginx** ?

Can someone guide me the proper way to solve this issue ?

> PS: The thing is, I had clicked on "Try Again" button after sometime and  installation was successfully done but I just wonder why the error came and should I resolve this from server side instead of ignoring this error as everything seems to be working now.
>
> I also found out this https://askubuntu.com/a/781195.
>
> Here they are suggesting to update `config.default.php` (/usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php) file, where you can find out like this line below:
>
> `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300;`
>
> To Make it to
>
> `$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;`
>
> Do I need to follow this to be able to make installation work error free next time or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the timeout in the Apache configuration. On Ubuntu usually it is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Open the file, find the following line and increase the value according to your needs:

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#

Timeout 300
```

Save the changes and restart the web server for the changes to take effect:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: This did not help. I increased it and tried to install a fresh copy of OctoberCMS after restarting the apache, but the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

found a fix.

If you've installed apache then you need to get to /etc/apache/ and find for mod-enabled folder and look for "fcgid.conf" and make changes to the following.

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 300

  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

If that file is not there then you need to configure for it and paste code into it.

Comment: I cannot find this file ("fcgid.conf") in my WAMP64 folder. I installed WAMP 3 on Windows 10 Home. I also have an Apache 2.4.17  on Windows 7 professional (64 bits) with same error and no "fcgid.conf" file. However, my first/test install on same Windows 7 was fine. Kindly assist.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am having the error when installing; at the "Building configuration files" stage.